# Generalizing sequence of fractions

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, fractions

I need to construct a formula for the $n$th term of the sequence $$\{2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5,\cdots \}$$

It's easy to come up with someting for every term after $2$, something like $\cfrac{n+1}{n+2}$ with lower limit $n=1$.

But after countless attempts I have not been able to come up with a formula that includes the very first term.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really need to, you can come up with some artificial way to express this. For instance:

$$u_n=\frac{n+1}{n+2}+\frac32\left\lfloor\frac{1}{n+1}\right\rfloor$$
where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) (so that $\lfloor\frac{1}{n+1}\rfloor$ is zero unless $n=0$).

But that is pointless, and just serves to obfuscate the fact that $n=0$ is a special case. Better is simply
$$
  u_n =
\begin{cases}
2  & \text{if $n=0$} \\
\frac{n+1}{n+2} & \text{if $n\ne 0$}
\end{cases}
$$